# how can i convert this xor encryption to c#?

Tags: c#, encryption, xor

I don't know what language is this code written in, but I'm trying to convert it to C#. I have a test sentence and an encrypted result for the original algorithm. My C# code generates a different result.

This is the original algorithm:

```
KeyStr='testKey'
j#=1; KeyLen#=Len(Clip(KeyStr))
Loop i#=1 To Len(Clip(InStr))
    OutStr[i#]=Chr(BXor(Val(InStr[i#]),Val(KeyStr[j#])+j#))
    !Message(InStr[i#]&'='&Val(InStr[i#])&' '&KeyStr[j#]&'='&Val(KeyStr[j#])&' '&OutStr[i#]&'='&Val(OutStr[i#]))
    j#+=1; If j#>KeyLen# Then j#=1.
End
```

I rewrote it to C# like this:

```
static string MyXOR(string data)
{
    string key = "testKey";
    string retValue = "";

    int i = 0;
    int x = 0;

    int[] cipher = new int[data.Length];
    x = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        //Console.Write((char)((data[i] ^ key[x])));
        retValue = retValue + (char)((data[i] ^ key[x]));
        cipher[i] = (data[i] ^ key[x]);
        x++;

        if (x >= key.Length)
            x = 0;
    }
    return retValue;
}
```

Comment: Can you put the input, the output the original code generates and the output your code generates to the question as well?

Answer (score 0):

I think like this:

```
//Console.Write((char)((data[i] ^ key[x])));
retValue = retValue + (char)((data[i] ^ (key[x] + x)));
cipher[i] = (data[i] ^ key[x]);
x++;
```